# how to scrape websites that using django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web-scraping

I wanted to create a robot to **scrape** a website with this address :

https://1xxpers100.mobi/en/line/

But the problem is that when I wanted to get data from this website
I realized that this website is using django because they are using
phrases like {{if group_name}} and others

there is a loop created with this kind of method and it creates table rows and
the information that I want is there.

when I am working with python and I download the html code I can't find
any content but "{{code}}" in there, but when I'm working with chrome developer tools (inspect) and when I work with console I can see the content that is inside of the table that I want

How can I get html codes that holds the content of that table like chrome tools
to get the information that I want from this website?

My way to get the codes is using python :

```
import urllib.request

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://1xxpers100.mobi/en/line/")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
```

Comment: it sounds to me like you're still in the parent object.  have you tried iterating through all the children of the objects returning `{{code}}`?  what python lib are you using to scrape this site?

Comment: I don't know how to do that !!! 
How can I get the children of this object?

Comment: could you add the code you are using to scrape the site and the output to your post?

Comment: If you're getting that when you view the HTML, this isn't Django at all, but a front-end framework - probably Angular.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: I actually worked with Django and I saw these sort of codes in it
but it doesn't really matter
I need to get all of the elements and their attributes to get my info from them

Comment: try using this https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.parser.html
or better yet use beatuifulsoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: How can I get the html elements exactly like google chrome inspect page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://1xxpers100.mobi/en/line/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

print(soup.encode("utf-8"))
```

here `'lmxl'` is what I use because it worked for the site I tested it on.  If you have trouble with that just try another parser.

another problem is that there is a character that isn't recognized by default.  so read the contents of `soup` using `utf-8`

**Extra Info**

This has nothing to do with django.  HTML has what is described as a "tree" like structure.  Where each set of tags is the parent of all children tags immediately inside it.  You just weren't reading deep enough into the tree.

[image: HTML]

Comment: thank you for your explanation but it still doesn't work

Comment: @amirhoseinmajidi try now, add the `endcode` part to the `print` line

Comment: same result :((

Comment: if you visit that page you can see that there is one element with class="events__row" but if you try it in inspect page it is defferent

Comment: when I get elements with var item = document.getElementsByClassName("events__row");

Comment: I get more than one element with that class (class="events__row" only this word for class not others)

Comment: that could be based on cookies and current session if it's a dynamic webpage, which the bot wouldn't be able to pick up.  I'm not sure if that's right, but it was my first thought.